# Could not run build action using Gradle distribution - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar

I am trying to add Gradle Nature into my Eclipse Project.
Gradle build is successfully running from my command prompt, but giving following error when tried to add Gradle Nature through Eclipse.

Error :

> Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error in the referenced Gradle build.
> Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-bin.zip'.

Note -

1. I am running Eclipse as admin.
2. from eclipse -> properties -> I am not able to see gradle option to change the "Specific Gradle Version"

Tried deleting the gradle-4.3-bin from C:/Users/name/.gradle/wrapper/dists

Comment: Is 4.3 the Gradle version declared in your app? What does `./gradlew --version` print on the command line?

Comment: gradle --version on cmd prints 6.8.3, and yes in build.gradle in dependencies it is written "classpath "some-website:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.31.8"